# DDD and Node.js: Good practice to have a repository with async callbacks?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, repository, domain-driven-design

Here's the thing:

- a client shouldn't be aware of the persistence mechanism used by a repository
- When, say, implementing a repository with MongoDB as persistence store, retrieving a value is done through async-callbacks
- a sync call can still be implemented using a callback, a async-call MUST be implemented using a callback. (Or futures, etc. but I don't want to go there)

To me means that repositories (at least for fetches) should have a callback defined in the interface, even though the implementation happens to be synchronous, e.g:

```
var repo = {
    cache: {},
    getById: function(id,callback){
        callback(null,this.cache[id]); 
    }
}
```

Since I might (will) change this soon to something like:

```
var repo = {
    getById: function(id,callback){
        mongoose.findOne({_id:id},callback);
    }
}
```

IMHO, for C/U/D the same need arises primarily for error reporting from the persistence layer.

in short: Do you consider it best practice to define repositories (in Nodejs, although not really relevant) with async callbacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider it a good practice if the remainder of the surrounding application code is also async. It certainly is a good practice technically, because repositories are IO bound and there is no sense in keeping blocking calling threads. The problem is that async callbacks result in a [continuation-passing style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) which incurs a learning curve and a degree of friction from most languages.

Comment: thanks for the confirmation. Using the continuation-passing style (didn't  know it was called that way) in Node through and through, although a bit cumbersome sometimes for the most simple of calls.